# xpath from response gives None

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

I am trying to get product name from the page:

```
https://www.michaelkors.com/ikat-print-tiered-shirtdress/_/R-US_MU98WXUC1Z\
```

Following is the statement I have used:

```
product-name =response.xpath('//ul[@class="brand-desc-container"]/li/h1/text').get()
```

However, product-name is empty. I have cross-checked with the website quite a few times and classes name and heirarchy seems correct.

Comment: Use `response.css('h1::text').get()` instead

Comment: @abdusco how do I make sure that it is returning h1 for that specific list

Comment: That worked, surprisingly. Can you please explain the intuition behind it?

Comment: Right now, it does, but you can use a more specific selector like `response.css('.product-name h1::text').get()`

Comment: A CSS selector is a more specialized version of XPath, which lets you target elements with a more readable syntax. Here's a tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp. And one from scrapy https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html. Keep in mind that behind the scenes all CSS selectors are converted to XPaths, so use the one you're comfortable with.

Comment: Your selector `'//ul[@class="brand-desc-container"]/li/h1/text'` should work when you change `text` into `text()`

Answer (score 1):

```py
product_name = response.xpath('//ul[@class="brand-desc-container"]/li[@class="product-name"]/h1/text()').get()
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? Thank you.

Comment: This code is using **XPath** query with HTML tag relations in web page.